# Text Field Border is not coming in only IPad2, In IPad Air or Resizable Ipad it is coming

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, ipad-2

[image: In Ipad2 it is coming like this]

[image: In Ipad Air it is coming like this]

I am running this app in simulator and in ipad2 and ipad air the style is coming different. Also tested in device same thing is happening. Any Idea how to fix this?

```
Code Snippet: 
answerField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by increasing textbox `borderwidth` by 1px.

Comment: Thank you @Aanabidden. I figured it out actually. Anyways Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but could it be that some of the simulators are running an older version of your app? Then you should go to "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings..." in the simulators that don't work for you.

Comment: No this is not working for me & also i tested it on device. Border is not coming in ipad air.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try like this:

#define BorderScaleWidth(width) [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] > 2.0 ? width / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] : width

It will give you correct width.